# Python/Django: virtualenv not recognizing app

Tags: python, django

I created a virtual environment (`virtualenv env`)and then created a python project for scraping websites. I installed the following using pip...

```
beautifulsoup4==4.4.1
Django==1.9
psycopg2==2.6.1
wheel==0.24.0
```

When ever I run the command `python manage.py runserver` I am getting the following error a `ImportError: No module named flower.views`
 error ('flower' in the name of my app).

The catch is that when I run the app outside of the virtual environment it works flawlessly, but if I bring it back into the virtual environment it breaks giving me the error state above.

Things I have tried...

1) checked INSTALLED APPS to make sure the app was there 
2) tried to `python manage.py migrate` to make sure I migrated (got the same error)
3) removed old `env` file and created new virtual environment using the `virtualenv env` command & subsequently installed all of the previously displayed requirements that I listed above using pip
4) Tried removing and recreating the `__init__.py` file in the `apps` folder
5) Looked for any similar SO posts regarding my troubles (found nothing).

Let me know if there are any files you would like me to post. I would happily oblige.

Comment: Did you activate your virtual environment *before* `pip install`?

Comment: Where is the `flower` module located in relation to your app?

Comment: flower_shop/apps/flower

Comment: Did you install all the packages? Try `pip install -r requiremts.txt` inside your virtualenv.

Comment: @drozzy Your response is much appreciated, although I was able to resolve the problem. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the directories structure changes when I enter my virtual environment.

***All I needed to do is change...*** 
 `from apps.flower.views import Index` 
***to***
 `from views import Index`
In my flower apps `urls.py` file.